# issues with structure with a pointer to it in a header file in c

Tags: c

```
`"a.h"
typedef struct a
{
File* fp;
int var;
};
extern a *pp;
---------------------
"a.c"
int show(a* ptr)
{
printf("%d",ptr->var); //ptr has no member named var
}
---------------------
"main.c"
#include"a.h"
main()
{
a *pp=(a*)malloc(sizeof(a));
printf("%d",pp->var);// pp has no member named var
show(pp);
}
```

---

in the two print statements above, it gives me an error that a certain member of the struct is not present. did i miss anything? is there something i must do in addition?
i have a situation like this- very similar, not exact. please help. it is very important and i dont have much time.

Comment: forgot to mention above, i included the function prototypes in the header file. so, thats not an issue.

Comment: Your `typedef` is invalid; there should be another `a` between the `}` and the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `a.c` you forgot to include `a.h` so that the definition of the structure is not available.
2. Even though you have declared a variable `pp`, you forgot to actually define it. See [External Variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable).

On a side note - do not use `typedef` with structures where it is not necessary (i.e. the type is supposed to be an opaque type). C programmers like things to be clear and explicit. If it is a structure, a "struct" hint is very much appreciated and is worse a bit more typing.

Also, the "main" function must return an integer result code, preferably `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` (defined in `stdlib.h`).

Comment: As an aside, the latest C standard doesn't require an explicit return from main.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Hm.. is it C99 or C11? I always thought that it is only true for C++ but not C.

Answer (score 4):

That won't even *compile,* let alone run. You have do active definition for `a` in `a.c`, your `typedef` is incomplete, `File` should be `FILE` (and you should include `stdio.h`), and that's about where I stopped reading and started rewriting. If you post code to demonstrate a problem, make sure you post the right code, not just something you made up :-)

If you want a working solution to start with, go for `a.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    FILE* fp;
    int var;
} a;
```

and `a.c`:

```
#include "a.h"
int show(a* ptr) {
    printf ("%d\n", ptr->var);
}
```

and, finally, `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"a.h"
int main (void) {
    a *pp = malloc (sizeof (a));
    printf ("%d\n", pp->var);
    show (pp);
    return 0;
}
```

Those will at least compile at which point you can begin the debugging process.

Comment: @paxdiablo: thanks for teaching me how to post code, you must already have understood i m new to stkovrflw. I cant give you the code that i am writing cuz its confidential. anyway, i tried the method you suggested long back. it does not work. still the same error.. its like you rephrased my question more readably!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
typedef struct 
{
File* fp;
int var;
} a;
```